# Fetching reviews and ratings from the Bazzarvoice API

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to use Bazzarvoice. I want to display rating and reviews using [Bazzarvoice API](https://developer.bazaarvoice.com/), I have a Bazaarvoice API key.

Can some one please tell me how to display reviews and ratings?

Thanks,
Irshad.

Comment: I assume you've seen the [Conversations API sample on GitHub](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/APITutorial) - does that do roughly what you want? (I don't know their API either.)

Comment: I have checked on GitHub but it didn't help me, Actually I want to get the particular products ratings and reviews using Bazaarvoice API, I have product ID and I want to send this Product ID to Bazaarvoice to get Ratings and reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch reviews and ratings for a single product ID using the filter option on the conversations API, e.g.

- [their sample feed](http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?apiversion=4.9&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo) from the [conversations sample page](https://developer.bazaarvoice.com/apis/conversations/tutorial)
- [their sample feed plus `&filter=ProductId:data-gen-9sirvya0r8detlnsxg0p46b6o`](http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?apiversion=4.9&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo&filter=ProductId%3Adata-gen-9sirvya0r8detlnsxg0p46b6o) to return reviews for the second product only.

(N.B. the `:` in that filter value should be URI-component-encoded to `%3A` but written unencoded above for clarity.)